# Constructor method in class not being called

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to create a class `Pixel` that will store the position and colors of a given pixel.

Here is my code so far:

```
<canvas id="kartina" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="textField" size="80">

<script>
//pass in coordinates and Canvas context
function Pixel(x,y,ctx){

    //assign coordinate properties
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

    //get an array with the color data for the pixel
    this.pixelData=function(){
        return ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
    };

    //assign color properties
    this.r=this.pixelData[0];
    this.g=this.pixelData[1];
    this.b=this.pixelData[2];

    //define toString method
    this.toString=function(){
                    var pixelToString=  "x: "+this.x+
                                        ", y: "+this.y+
                                        ", R: "+this.r+
                                        ", G: "+this.g+
                                        ", B: "+this.b;
                    return pixelToString;
    };
}

//test the class
var canvas=document.getElementById("kartina");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var pixel=new Pixel(100,100,ctx);
textField.value=pixel.toString();
</script>
```

The output from `toString()` is:

```
x: 100, y: 100, R: undefined, G: undefined, B: undefined
```

So I know that the coordinate properties are being assigned correctly, but the `pixelData` initialization function is not being executed when `new Pixel()` constructs the instance.  I want the object's constructor to call this initialization function; I thought this was the way to do it.  How do I set up the constructor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pixelData` is a **function**, you need to *invoke* it to get your desired results:

```
//assign color properties
this.r=this.pixelData()[0];
this.g=this.pixelData()[1];
this.b=this.pixelData()[2];
```

Or better yet:

```
var pData = this.pixelData();

this.r=pData[0];
this.g=pData[1];
this.b=pData[2];
```

Comment: Do I really have to call it 3 times?  I just want to call it once and get the array, then fill in the individual color properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing your this.pixelData() function as if it were an array using [] square brackets.

The function never gets called at all because you are treating it as an array instead of calling the function and then treating the result as an array.

Change this:

```
this.r=this.pixelData[0];
this.g=this.pixelData[1];
this.b=this.pixelData[2];
```

To this:

```
this.r=this.pixelData()[0];
this.g=this.pixelData()[1];
this.b=this.pixelData()[2];
```

Or to avoid calling it three times:

```
//assign color properties
var pixelData = this.pixelData()
this.r = pixelData[0];
this.g = pixelData[1];
this.b = pixelData[2];
```